# Iterating through items in Capybara

Tags: loops, iteration, capybara

I've got a page containing multiple elements of class .block. In Capybara, I want to be able to loop through and refer to each of the elements with this class before completing an action.

However, none of the code I've tried so far has worked. Here's what I've tried:

```
within('.block:nth-child(1)') do
  find('.Button').click
end

page.find('.block').all.first.find('Button').click

page.find('.block').all[1].find('Button').click
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You want to use the `all` method (see http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method).

An example of outputting the text of each element (ie iterating) with class 'block' would be:

```
page.all(:css, '.block').each do |el|
    puts el.text
end
```

`page.all` returns an array of matching elements. So if you just want the second matching element, you can do:

```
page.all(:css, '.block')[1]  #Note that it is 0-based index
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I use that to refer just to the second element? I can see how to refer to the first, but not any others after that

Comment: `page.all` will return an array of matching elements, so you can use the standard array methods. Example added to answer.

Comment: Hi Justin, I'm a different guy with the same problem. Trying the 1st method you explained with the `puts el.text` but getting `#<Enumerator:0x2aee5c0>`. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Hi @mickael. I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you open a new question and include a sample html and code that reproduces your problem?