# How to iterate with more than one element on the page

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have several buttons to click on the same page. How do I iterate and click on each of them?

```
def btnConectar()


   elements = all("button[data-control-name='srp_profile_actions']").count 

    puts elements

    first("button[data-control-name='srp_profile_actions']").click 
    find("section[class=modal]")
    find("button[class='button-primary-large ml1']").click

end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through items in Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427913/iterating-through-items-in-capybara)

Comment: What does clicking on each button do? Does it change the current page (thereby making the rest of the buttons stale) or does it just change the state of something on the current page?

Answer (score 1):

`all` returns an Array like Capybara::Result object. You can iterate through that using the standard ruby enumerable methods.

```
all("button[data-control-name='srp_profile_actions']").each do |el|
  el.click
  find("section[class=modal]") # Not sure what this is for - if it's an expectation/assertion it should be written as such
  click_button(class: %w(button-primary-large ml1) 
end
```

That will work as long as clicking on the button doesn't cause the browser to move to another page.

If clicking does cause the browser to move to another page then all the rest of the elements in the Capybara::Result object will become stale (resulting in a stale element reference error on the next iteration) and you won't be able to iterate any more. If that is your case then details on what exactly you're doing will be necessary.  Questions like does the original button still exist on the page after clicking the `button-primary-large` button, or can you iterate by just clicking the first matching button over and over? If it does still exist is it changed in any way to indicate it's already been clicked, or is the number/order of buttons on the page guaranteed to be stable? It would probably help to understand if you posted a fragment of the HTML for the first and second iteration.

Comment: In my case, after clicking on the desired button, a modal is enabled in the front and the back screen with the other buttons that I want to click is disabled, being necessary to click on the button of the front screen and then to try to click the other buttons of the screen of after Because of this it is not iterating on all the buttons on the screen. I hope I was clear in the explanation.

Comment: @MayconSilva you’re going to need to provide actual details about what error the code I provided produces - just saying it doesn’t work doesn’t tell us anything

Comment: @MayconSilva Updated the answer with the questions you need to answer if clicking the button just cause the page to change, thereby making all current elements stale.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def btnConectar()

        page.all("button[data-control-name='srp_profile_actions']").each do |el|

        while page.has_css?("button[data-control-name='srp_profile_actions']")  

        el.click #Click the button
        find("section[class=modal]") #Modal mapping
        click_button(class: %w(button-primary-large ml1)) #Click the button
        sleep 3

        end

    end

end
```

Comment: I've tried the syntax above, but it's not yet iterating with the buttons on the page. It clicks the first button but does not proceed with the iteration and displays the following error: stale element reference: "element is not attached to the document page"

Comment: Update/edit your question rather than adding an answer with more questions in it.